# Can I Use Having Keyword With 2 Columns?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have 2 tables for keeping stocks of several products. 1 table for current stock of a product per warehouse and the other table is to create low stock warnings.

My stocks table is like this;

`id  |  warehouse  |  product  |  quantity`

And tracking table is like this;

`id  |  product  |  quantity`

This means if total of quantity columns in stocks table for a product is less than quantity column in tracking table, it has a low stock.

I am using these SQL to fetch products that have low stocks:

```
SELECT t.id AS t_id, t.product AS t_product, t.type AS t_type, t.quantity AS t_quantity FROM stocks s LEFT JOIN tracking t ON s.product = t.product GROUP BY s.product HAVING SUM(s.quantity) < t_quantity
```

It is working actually but my SQL editor throwing an error like this;

*Column t_quantity must be either aggregated, or mentioned in GROUP BY clause*

Is my SQL right or should I use something different?

Comment: It's not aboue `HAVING`, it's about `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL editor is probably running with `sql_mode` "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY", see documentation here: [MariaDB Knowledgebase: sql_mode: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/#only_full_group_by)

... or your SQL editor is otherwise built or configured to allow only queries with "full" `GROUP BY` clauses.

To answer your question: Your SQL query is "correct" for `sql_mode` without "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY".

I think you can simply list the same columns in the `GROUP BY` clause as you have in the `SELECT` clause to make your query work in both sql_modes:

```
SELECT t.id AS t_id, 
  t.product AS t_product, 
  t.type AS t_type,
  t.quantity AS t_quantity
FROM stocks s 
    LEFT JOIN tracking t ON s.product = t.product
GROUP BY t.id, t.product, t.type, t.quantity
HAVING SUM(s.quantity) < t_quantity;
```

Comment: Is it possible to write a query that satisfies both when ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled and disabled. Can I use a subquery instead of t_quantity like this: HAVING SUM(s.quantity) < (SELECT quantity FROM tracking WHERE product = s.product)

Comment: @cemekkazan I can't seem to make your subquery work, but I've updated the answer with a query that I think maybe works correctly in both sql_modes - but please test this with your own data!